# How to mock APIs using karate

Tags: java, spring-boot, karate

Using karate I am realizing a real api request. How to mock these APIs that I am not using my real database? is using wiremock will resolve the problem or does karate have a way to mock the requests?

Just I want to write an integration test using karate but I want to use a mocked APIs. I tried karate and heard about wiremock.
What is your advise?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Karate is a replacement for Wiremock. Start by reading the docs: https://karatelabs.github.io/karate/karate-netty/